# Sequence of random variables with infinite expectation, but partial sum converges

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on problem 2.2.5 from Durrett Probability Theory and examples edition 4.

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots $ be i.i.d. with $P(X_i>x)=\frac{e}{x\log(x)}$ for $x\geq e$. Show that $E(|X_i|)=\infty,$ but there is a sequence of constants $\mu_n\rightarrow \infty$ so that $S_n/n - \mu_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

So far I have been able to show $E(|X_i|)=\infty$. I did this using the following inequality I have from my probability theory class. Let $X\geq 0$ be a random variable and let $0<a<\infty$ then:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty E(X\geq ka)\leq E(X/a)\leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty P(X>ka).
$$

So what I did was bound $E(|X_i|/e)$ below by $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|X_i|\geq ke)$. Using what I know about the $X_i$ I showed that this sum is infinite using the comparison test and so I got $E(|X_i|)=\infty.$

Now I am stuck on how to find the $\mu_n$. I was thinking that maybe I could use a truncation of the random variables somehow, i.e. something like $\overline{X_i}=X_i 1_{|X_i|\leq ei}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually very NEARLY correct: if you remember precisely, the proof of Weak Law of Large Numbers tried to estimate $|S_n/n-E(S_n'/n)|$ where $S_n'$ was the sum of truncated r.v.s.

So let's first try to see whether the original truncation holds i.e. $Y_{k,n}=X_k1\{|X_k|\leq n\}$ for fixed $n$. Then for fixed $n$ we have $Y_{k,n}$ are i.i.d.

$E(Y_{1,n})=e\log\log n$ .

So we can always choose $\mu_n=e\log\log n$.

Now the most important question: Is our truncation correct? Well if you go through the proof of this step in any standard probability book, you'd see that we needed to have $nP(|X_1|\geq n)\to0$. This actually followed from $E|X_1|<\infty$. But it is enough to check $nP(|X_1|\geq n)\to0$.

Here, $nP(|X_1|\geq n)=\dfrac{e}{\log n}\to0$ and so our $\mu_n$ are indeed the correct one!!

Comment: Hey @LandonCarter how do we get that $E(Y_{1,n})=e \log \log n$ for all $k\leq n?$

Comment: That is a typo. Please ignore $k\leq n$". Editing it.

Comment: Ah okay, This comment made me look at the weak law of large numbers in my book and it says all that we need is that $xP(|X_i|>x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Which we will have, thanks for your help.

Comment: I am getting $E[Y_{k,n}]=e\log\log n+e(1-1/\log n)$. How did you get $e\log\log n$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901364/expectations-of-indicator-functions-and-random-variables/3901381?noredirect=1#comment8046028_3901381